# Working with Android Sensor with google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment, sensors

I am first time developing an application on Android platform and trying to connect sensor with google map. Individually, sensor and google maps are working fine, however, when I try connect it through `Fragment`, it gives an error.

Error:

> incompatible types:  cannot be converted to OnMapReadyCallback

Here is my sample code:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) { 
  if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {
     textLIGHT_reading.setText("LIGHT1: " + event.values[0]);
     updateCamera(event.values[0]);
  }
}

private void updateCamera(float degree) {
  if (mMap == null) {
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
  }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is your fragment implementing `OnMapReadyCallback`?

Comment: and if you may please post the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was using wrong libraries, i recreated the project and change the code, as first time google maps takes time to download so better to write code in else statement.

```
if ( mMap == null){ 
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            Log.d("mapFragment","Degree--" + googleMap1);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            } else {
            Log.d("MapNOTNULL","Degree---" + mMap);
              mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(bearing));
            }
```